# Matching a string

Tags: string, pattern-matching, rust

I have this

```
fn main() {
    let args = os::args();
    let first_args = args[1].to_string();
    match first_args {
        "test" => println!("Good!"),
        _      => println!("No test ?!"),
    }
}
```

but during compilation, I get this error:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `collections::string::String`, found `&'static str` (expected struct collections::string::String, found &-ptr)
src/command_line_arguments.rs:7         "test" => println!("Good!"),
                                        ^~~~~~
```

Can someone please help me to understand this better? What would be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two kinds of strings in Rust, as explained by the [Strings section of the Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html).  Short version: there's strings that *own* their contents (`String`), and strings that don't (`&str`).

`first_args` is `String`, but string literals are `&str`s (as noted by the error).  To do this, you need to turn `first_args` back into a borrowed string, like so:

```
fn main() {
    let args = os::args();
    let first_args = args[1].to_string();
    match &*first_args {
        "test" => println!("Good!"),
        _      => println!("No test ?!"),
    }
}
```

To just clarify what `&*` does: owning containers (like `String` and `Vec`) can "decay" into borrowed references to their contents.  `*` is used to "dereference" the container into its contents (*i.e.* `*first_args` takes the `String` and provides access to the underlying `str`), whilst the `&` re-borrows that value, turning it back into a regular reference.

Comment: As a minor optimization, you could use `let first_args = &args[1];` This prevents making a new allocated string. You would then need to use `match &**first_args`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Even better: `let first_args = &*args[1]; match first_args { ...`

Comment: use `first_args.as_str()` or `first_args.as_ref()`.